# Facing issue with bcrypt module

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

We are trying to set up a project on node version 12, but we got an error of bcrypt module. We try all solutions on stack overflow and other site but not able to resolve.
[image]

Comment: you need to install `bcrypt` in the current directory/project, check your `dependencies` in pacakage.json if you have it...

Answer (score 2):

This shows that module bcrypt is missing in node_modules.

```
npm install bcrypt
```

If you have not installed any node_modules, do this

```
npm install
```

To check you may check node_modules folder in your directory structure.

Comment: can you provide snippet of your package.json?

Comment: Also, try installing the specific version of bcrypt such as ** npm install bcrypt@3.0.6.**